# Planning Javascript Word API out of beta?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

We currently use some functions from the beta release of the word API (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js)

Does anybody know when functions like CreateDocument will be available in https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js

Our plugin is now rejected for the Office appstore because of the use of the beta js.

any info is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets.md) for updates about when WordApi1.4 version is made available in GA. There is no definite date available yet.